# default custom background image not saved in database when creating a new site

Tags: theme-customizer, custom-background

I am a theme author and the theme I made is used in a multisite environment.
I have added the `custom_background` feature to this theme, with a default image and everything works as expected : the user can change the image and see the result live is the Theme Customizer before putting it online.

Here is the custom_background declaration:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'user83643_theme_features');
function user83643_theme_features(){
    add_theme_support( 'custom-background' , array(
        'default-color' => '1878A0',
        'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/default.jpg',
        'wp-head-callback' => '__return_false',
    ));
}
```

However, when a fresh new site is created in the network, the default image does not appear in the frontend. I can see it in the backend in the theme customizer, but I have to save it once to activate it on the frontend : `get_theme_mod('background_image')` returns `false` before I save it once.

Any idea how to save the default image (and color) in the database upon the first theme activation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you mean "`get_theme_mod('background_image')` returns `false`" *before* I "save it once to activate it"

If that is the case, [`get_theme_mod`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) accepts a default parameter. Check the Codex:

> $name
>       (string) (required) Theme modification name.
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```
>
> $default
>       (boolean|string) (optional)
>
> ```
>     Default: false
> ```

Pass your default image as the second parameter to that function and you should be set.

Comment: I have edited my question following your recommendations to make it clearer.